# Node, servidor enviar informação para página (controle de senha banco, laboratório...)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Boa noite!

Não sei se é possível implementar a seguinte situação: tenho uma página html que é um monitor (possui o ultimo numero chamado), na segunda página html, o usuário poderá clicar para solicitar o próximo numero. Eu até consigo trocar informações via socket, porém somente com a página que foi clicada, eu teria que atualizar a outra página que é o monitor. Caso não consiga dessa forma, teria que verificar o endpoint a cada instante para saber se o numero foi alterado. Alguma sugestão, mesmo que não seja via socket?

Solução atual que não funcionou:

server.js

```
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express')
var socketio = require('socket.io')
var app = express(server)
var server = http.Server(app)
var io = socketio(server)

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log('Passei aqui!!!');

  req.socket.on('login_monitor', function(data, callback) {
    req.socket.join('monitor');
    callback();
   });

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/monitor.html');
});

app.get('/teste', function(req, res){
  console.log('TESTE!!!');
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('echo', function(data){
      socket.emit('echo', 'Servidor--->');
      console.log(data);

       socket.on('echo', function(data) {
        socket.emit('echo', 'Servidor--->'); //envia para quem invocou o echo
        io.to('monitor').emit('echo', 'Funcionou!!!!!'); //envia para o monitor
      });

    });
  });
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('echo', function(data){
    socket.emit('echo', 'Servidor--->');
    console.log(data);
  });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Echo server</title>

    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('echo', function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
      socket.emit('echo', 'this is a message');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Próximo cliente (Clique aqui)</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

monitor.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Echo server</title>

    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('echo', function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
      socket.emit('login_monitor', 'this is a message', function(){
        console.log('logado como monitor');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Senha 609 caixa 3</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um login para o monitor

monitor.html

```
  socket.emit('login_monitor', {/*envie parâmetros se necessário*/}, function(){
      console.log('logado como monitor');
  });
```

server.js

```
  socket.on('login_monitor', function(data, callback) {
      socket.join('monitor');
      callback();
  });
```

Agora que os sockets dos monitores podem ser identificados com a chave 'monitor', você pode enviar mensagens para eles no echo

```
socket.on('echo', function(data) {
  socket.emit('echo', 'Servidor--->'); //envia para quem invocou o echo
  io.to('monitor').emit('echo', 'Servidor--->'); //envia para o monitor
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, vou fazer as alterações agora no fim da tarde.  Valeu!!!

Comment: Estou iniciando com Node e Javascript, minha dúvida pode ser muito simples, mas pela falta de conhecimento. Incluí o código no monitor.hrml, esse código é responsável por identificar a página, certo? Alterei o server.js  no endpoint raiz '/' para identificar o monitor no back-end. A cada chamada '/teste' incluí o ultimo trecho de código que você enviou.  Estou com erro ao acessar raiz 0.0.0.0:8080.  Vou atualizar os códigos na pergunta.  Obrigado pela força.

Comment: Estudei sobre socket, a sua resposta está show. Não estava conseguindo entender.  Valeu!!!